# fastflow simple test may get memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, fastflow

I have tested fastflow in g++ 4.4.6 recently , the following is quite a simple test :

```
using namespace ff ;
int g1=0 ;

class Stage1 : public ff_node{
public :
    void *svc(void *task){
        g1++ ;
        if(g1 >= 10000)
        {
            return NULL ;
        }
        char *p=(char*) calloc(sizeof(char),10) ;
        return ((void*)p) ;
    }
} ;
class Stage2 : public ff_node{
public :
    void *svc(void *task){
        free(task) ;
        return GO_ON ;
    }
} ;

int main(int agrc,char *argv[])
{
    ff_pipeline pipe ;
    pipe.add_stage(new Stage1()) ;
    pipe.add_stage(new Stage2()) ;

    for(int idx=0;idx<1000000;idx++)
    {
        g1 = 0 ;
        if(pipe.run_and_wait_end() <0){
            error("running pipeline\n");
            return -1 ;
        }
        printf("idx=(%d)\n",idx) ;
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

This test is  simple enough , but I observe the memory usage from top in linux, 
I have found the "VIRT" and "RES" are increasing , I don't get it , since Stage1
allocate memory , Stage2 will free it , quite simple implement , May I ask 
what I miss in this test sample ?!

Edit :

```
class Stage1 : public ff_node{
public :
    void *svc(void *task){
        g1++ ;
        if(g1 >= 10000)
        {
            return NULL ;
        }
        //char *p=(char*) calloc(sizeof(char),10) ;
        //return ((void*)p) ;
        std::auto_ptr<char> x(new char(10)) ;
        return ((void*)x.get()) ;
    }
} ;
class Stage2 : public ff_node{
public :
    void *svc(void *task){
        //free(task) ;
        return GO_ON ;
    }
} ;
```

using auto_ptr still get the same problem ....

Comment: please use smart pointer

Comment: @Bryan Chen,thanks for information,unique_ptr can not used in g++ 4.4.6 , auto_ptr might be the solution, I just like to know why memory leak happen in this simple test ?

Comment: Smart pointers (especially autio_ptr) have no use here. Memory usage increases even if you don't use allocation within stages. Are you sure pipeline is indended for multiple subsequent runs?

Comment: @keltar,thanks for information, run_and_wait_end() called many times seems to cause leak , but if run_and_wait_end() can called just once , look like this library usage is limited , I don't see any tutorial call run_and_wait_end() many times , it is just my test only !!

Comment: Ok, pinned down the problem. You returning `GO_ON`, which keeps thread alive. Returning NULL removes memory usage increase. I have no ideas how fastflow supposed to work (see it first time), but i assume it's just not correct use case. From what i see, data should be feeded to input and gathered from output, with just one run call.

Comment: To all advising smart pointers: and how exactly you think it would work here? Please show example. (hint - it wouldn't)

Comment: @keltar,thanks,I am new in fastflow , I think to have run_and_wait_end() called many times is quite a normal way to do, so while observing leak really confuse me , I might miss something , but no document I refered mentioned ~~